# Not able to complete Drupal ubercart free order

Tags: php, drupal-7, ubercart

last week we face a problem with ubercart free order.
When we will try to submit order with free (using coupon) order. its redirect to checkout page from order review page.
order with amount is working fine.
I also try order with 0 amount, face same issue.

we also test same code and database in local and stage server. its working fine.

There is no error logs or apache logs that help me. i already check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found there is a broken image which is oppose to submit order using ajax.

if you guys face this type of issue please check your js error from console. and try to resolved them.Its work for me.